# Xamarin forms: converted PCL to .net standard libraries and now I can't add new XAML pages

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I recenty went through the process of converting all PCL's in my solution to .net standard libraries (not sure if its related nor not, just mentioning it in case).
Now, when I try and add a page, It adds the Xaml and the xaml.cs files into the project without any link or connection, so they wont compile:

[image]

Googling suggests I can go in and edit the .csproj to add a dependency between the two, but this is a horrible solution long term.
Any way to fix this "properly"?

I've tried dragging and dropping existing files in from windows explorer into VS2017, adding new through the add new dialog, adding existing through add existing and it all exhibits the same behaviour.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK, to answer my own question. Seems like you need to put in a workaround for the time being:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/288205/#Comment_288205

In the .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55591 -->
    <None Remove = "**\*.xaml" />

    < Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include = "**\*.xaml" SubType="Designer" Generator="MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And remove all existing XAML Pages referenced in the .csproj file such as EmbeddedResources and Compile directives